# Como agrupar Markers no Google Maps API iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, marker

Como posso agrupar os markers de uma área quando o usuário diminui o zoom do mapa, para reduzir a poluição visual de marker's no mapa e mostrar somente um marker, com um número dentro para indicar a quantidade de pontos daquela região?

Comment: Da uma olhada [aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=da&csw=1) e [nessa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175605/marker-clustering-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios) pergunta do SO.

Comment: Obrigado, vou estar verificando e ja digo no que resultou!

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa biblioteca [aqui](https://github.com/itsbonczek/kingpin) no GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Galera, embora ja tenha passado um certo tempo, vou deixar aqui a solução que encontrei para ajudar outras pessoas que enfrentam o mesmo problema. Utilizei API para resolver o problema:

https://github.com/lahavamir27/cluster-google